# How do I make multiple components within a Container inherit the Container's computed width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs4

[Here is a Sencha fiddle of my tab panel setup.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2m0) Buttons are dynamically added to a `vbox` tabs container that is part of an `hbox` layout setup. The tabs container's width is determined by the `flex` property.

I've tried setting every button's `width: '100%'`, but upon looking at the [Sencha docs on button.width](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-width), I find that `width` takes an integer value representing pixels. I've tried setting the width in `style`, but I've only succeeded in making the button's width be the width of the screen.

Help and an explanation of the underlying CSS concepts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try using `width:inherit;`?

Comment: @PHPglue `width:inherit` makes the buttons huge for some reason. Probably inheriting from the document itself? I've updated the fiddle accordingly and commented out my attempt

Comment: Set a width on the parent.

Comment: @PHPglue The parent's width depends on the children's widths... namely, the width of the widest button I'm adding to the container.

Comment: So you want each button to stretch to the width of the largest button?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `stretchmax` option.

```
var locationCameraList=[];

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {

        var buttonArr = [];

        for (i = 0; i < locationCameraList.length; ++i) {
            var tabName = locationCameraList[i].location, 
                index = i;
            var tab = {
                xtype: 'button',
                cls: 'tab'+index,
                text: tabName,
                scale: 'medium'

            };
            buttonArr.push(tab);
            console.log(i)
        }

        var forms = {
            xtype: 'container',
            flex: 4,
            layout: 'fit',
            align: 'stretch',
            html: 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
        };

        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Foo',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'container',
                items: buttonArr,
                flex: 1,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretchmax'
                },
                autoScroll: true,
                height: 200
            }, forms]
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple answer!